# How-To configure the Header Section in IIS7 to host multiple Web sites on the same IP address

Tags: iis-7

If you have 1 IP Address on Windows server 2008 (iis7) and you want to host multiple web sites, I have been told you need to configure the Header section. anyone have an example of that ?

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the website and click "Edit Bindings." Enter the DNS name and port that the site will run on. Doing this will allow multiple sites on port 80, however they can only be reached by the DNS name specified in the header, not by the IP.